# Google Analytics API oauth exception "invalid_grant" with Service Account. Same code on two servers. Only one works

Tags: php, api, exception, oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm querying the Analytics API via a **Service Account**.

I have written the code on the dev server and it works without issues.
When running the same code on the production server, it throws this:

> Google_AuthException: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
> "error" : "invalid_grant" }'

I've tried creating another Service account, and the behavior is the same.

The oAuth IETF draft (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31) says this about the error:

```
     invalid_grant
           The provided authorization grant (e.g. authorization
           code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
           invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
           URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
           another client.
```

Here is the code I've written:

```
$GA_CLIENT_ID = 'XX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$GA_APP_EMAIL = 'XX@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$GA_APP_NAME = 'XX';
$GA_KEY_FILE = 'XX';

// create client object and set app name
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($GA_APP_NAME); // name of your app

// set assertion credentials
$client->setAssertionCredentials(
        new Google_AssertionCredentials(
            $GA_APP_EMAIL, // email you added to GA
            array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
            file_get_contents($GA_KEY_FILE)  // keyfile you downloaded
            ));

// other settings
$client->setClientId($GA_CLIENT_ID);           // from API console
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');  // this may be unnecessary?

// create service and get data
$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
$result = $service->data_ga->get($ids, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, $optParams);
return $result;
```

I've also tried a solution suggested here (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gs-discussion/3y_2XVE2q7U%5B1-25%5D) using authenticatedRequest() instead of Google_AnalyticsService:

```
$req = new Google_HttpRequest($apiUrl);
$resp = $client::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
$result = json_decode($resp->getResponseBody(), true);
```

This alternative also works on the dev server, but not on the production one.

I am totally clueless on this one. Has anyone seen this/fixed it?

Thanks!

Comment: Biggest thing to check is that the date/time on your servers are correct.  Check vs time.gov.  Even a few seconds off can count-- the assertion flow requires the time be exactly correct.

Comment: Ryan, that time offset was the issue. I've installed ntpdate to sync the clock. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apparently the problem was the system time being off. Worked by sync-ing via NTP with:

<strike>`sudo ntpdate npt.ubuntu.com`</strike>

`sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org`

#### Edit

As @RafaSashi suggested below, the `pool.ntp.org` server is more reliable. Use that instead of `ntp.ubuntu.com` *(which was the first working one I tried, thus the initial choice)*.

Comment: can't we just set timezone?

Comment: It's been a long time since I dealt with that. I don't remember if the TZ was wrong. I guess it should work if that was the thing..

Comment: Thank you for this, solved my problem as well. My clock was off by hours. To synchronize the time, I followed these instructions [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-12-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Awesome this worked for me, thanks!! My time was only off by a couple minutes. For windows users, click on the clock -> Change date & time -> Click tab 'Internet Time' -> Click change settings -> Click update now

Comment: Solved my problem as well. Ran "sudo ntpdate npt.ubuntu.com" to adjust the server time

Comment: @nbarth - glad it helped. Edited the answer with the straight-fwd ntp solution.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore:
Error resolving npt.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
18 Jan 12:02:31 ntpdate[7355]: Can't find host npt.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
18 Jan 12:02:31 ntpdate[7355]: no servers can be used, exiting

Comment: @AdilOuchraa See @rafasashi's answer below if this host's not working. Use `pool.ntp.org`. Additionally see: http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html

Answer (score 2):

The invalid grant can also be caused if you use the wrong "ServiceAccountId". It should be the email associated with the client id in the service account client id in the google apis access page. You'd also have to add this user to the google analytics account that you're planning to access.

This tripped me up because I assumed the email address they were referring to was the email address of my google account, since I used the same google account to get api access as I do for google analytics. I know Vir's already figured his out, just thought I'd add this in case someone else comes across the same question and, like me, their computer seems to be in sync with NTP.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Valer's answer:

First, you’ll need to install NTP if it isn’t already installed. For Debian or Ubuntu, that would be this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

For Redhat or CentOS, you’ll need to use this one:

```
yum install ntp
```

If the synchronization via `npt.ubuntu.com` doesn't work try :

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

**Resources**

- http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-sync-your-linux-server-time-with-network-time-servers-ntp/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 1):

There are two major reasons for **[invalid_grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2)** error which you have to take care prior to the POST request for Refresh Token and Access Token.

1. Request header must contain "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2. Your request payload should be url encoded Form Data, don't send as json object.

[RFC 6749 OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) defined **invalid_grant** as:
*The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.*

I found another good article, [here](https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35) you will find many other reasons for this error.

https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35

[Google Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) is best tool which help you how to send request.
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground